# unix grep to search all the strings and making sure all strings present in the input

Tags: linux, unix

```
9801a79de381:logs yik087$ tail -1 access.log | grep -rE "CLIENT_APP_ID|OVERALL_RESPONSETIME|STATUSm" | wc -l
       1
9801a79de381:logs yik087$ tail -1 access.log | grep -rE "CLIENT_APP_ID|OVERALL_RESPONSETIME|STATUSm" | wc -l
       1
```

I need to search all this `CLIENT_APP_ID` , `OVERALL_RESPONSETIME`, `STATUS` in the inout to grep. Grep should return me 1 only if all three found else 0. Is there a way I can acheive this ?

Any hint on this will be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `grep term1 | grep term2 | grep term3`?

Comment: can you try this: `grep -e "CLIENT_APP_ID -e "OVERALL_RESPONSETIME" -e "STATUS" log_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link detailing some logical operations you can do with grep: [Grep OR, AND, NOT operators](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/). It seems you need to AND the three search parameters, not OR.